# How does the save system work?

Tags: watch-dogs

At which points does the game usually save?

Do I always have to get back to my hideout and sleep to make absolutely sure that I don't lose any progress (like hacked accounts or money collected from ATMs)? The game seemed to suggest that I should sleep in the hideout to save the progress, but I am not sure if this is even necessary.

Apparently your progress also gets saved after you start or finish a mission or mini game. What exactly are the points after which I safely can quit the game without having to worry to lose anything.

Answer (score 9):

The game saves after every progression in game, like doing any kind of mission, playing a mini-game or doing fixer contracts. Pretty much *everything* saves the game, even taking money out of an ATM.
Look for this icon on the left side of your screen, whenever you see it, it means the game is being saved.

[image]

Comment: What about things like privacy invasions, normal crimes or finding the hidden weapon caches? Does the game save in those instances?

Comment: Privacy invasions, finding weapon caches - anything that gets removed from the map after interaction automatically save the game. I will try to confirm normal crimes, but I believe it saves the game as well.

Comment: I can confirm that preventing crimes and even taking money out of ATM saves the game. Pretty much everything you do that matters, except hacking for money, saves the game

Comment: Ok, great to know, thank you. I know about the save sign, but I am usually to busy in the game doing other things to notice it.

Comment: Only thing I would add is that when you are Done playing the game (going to turn it off) I suggest that is when you go and rest to make sure you are going to pick up where you left off... The overall lack of access to save information in Watch Dogs actually really bugs me.

Comment: Well, resting in the hideout is a guaranteed save, so yes, I would recommend doing it before turning the game off as well. However, the game saves after almost everything, so you probably wouldn't lose much, if anything, if you didn't rest at the hideout.

Answer (score 1):

The game does not save when you purchase skills, pick up new guns, or find money (such as inside vehicles). The game saves after story missions, although I'm not sure if it saves just the story or other things as well. The game seems to save after side missions, but it doesn't seem like skills or guns are saved after these missions; you must still sleep in order for them to be saved. I'm not sure if this is how it works for everyone, or if I have a bug on mine.